# Continuity of complex-valued polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity, proof-writing

While I was reading the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra supplied by Rudin in its "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" I realized that he has never rigorously proved the continuity of a complex valued polynomial (i.e.: a function defined by the expression $P(z) = c_0 + c_1z^1 + ... + c_nz^n$ where $c_n$ denotes a sequence of complex numbers and $z$ is an arbitrary complex number), or at least he did not according to what I could recall and check.
Therefore, I would like to know if there is some easy proof of this fact, that is, I prefer to avoid proving everything from scratch and instead I was trying to do it by assuming usual facts about continuity of real-valued functions, continuity of maps into products and continuity of composite maps.

---

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: The proof for real coefficients will do.

Comment: Theorem 4.9 proves that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions then $f+g$ and $f g$ are also continuous, from which it follows that polynomials are continuous.

Comment: @jjag, I guess one also needs to know that constants are continuous, and that $f(x)=x$ is continuous.